# How to make function as a list and store it in variable?

Tags: python, list

```
import spacy
import scispacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_sci_lg')

for text1 in df1['priceDescription']:
    doc1 = nlp(text1)
   
    for text2 in df2['Description']:
        doc2 = nlp(text2)

        similarity = doc1.similarity(doc2)

        #print(doc1.text, doc2.text, similarity)
        output = (f'{doc1.text:26} | {doc2.text:26} | {similarity:.2}')
        print(output)
```

This is my code so how I can store the above function in the list so that I can store a list in one variable.

Output may be something like this

```
mylist = [for text1 in df1['priceDescription'].....]
```

I want output above format

can anyone help me please to solve this problem?

Thank You.

Comment: Do you mean, you want the things that you are currently printing to stdout to instead be gathered up as a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes the strings you were previously printing to stdout, and instead gathers them into a list and returns the list.  For future reference, you should note how little I had to change to make this work.

```
import spacy

def convert(nlp):
    result = []
    for text1 in df1['priceDescription']:
        doc1 = nlp(text1)
        for text2 in df2['Description']:
            doc2 = nlp(text2)
            similarity = doc1.similarity(doc2)
            result.append(f'{doc1.text:26} | {doc2.text:26} | {similarity:.2}')
    return result

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_sci_lg')
mylist = convert(nlp)

print(mylist)
```

It's worth pointing out that this can also be done as a generator:

```
import spacy

def convert(nlp):
    for text1 in df1['priceDescription']:
        doc1 = nlp(text1)
        for text2 in df2['Description']:
            doc2 = nlp(text2)
            similarity = doc1.similarity(doc2)
            yield f'{doc1.text:26} | {doc2.text:26} | {similarity:.2}'

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_sci_lg')
mylist = list(convert(nlp))

print(mylist)
```